# Wireless Tools: how to cross compile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I tried to cross compile Wireless Tools for MIPS architecture by modifying Makefile

```make
## Compiler to use (modify this for cross compile).
#CC = gcc
CC=/home/mips-gcc472-glibc216-64bit-r2.3.3/mips-gcc472-glibc216-64bit/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc

## Other tools you need to modify for cross compile (static lib only).
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
```

I can build it successfully with there modified Makefile, but the tool fail to install. So I think something wrong with my modified Makefile. Do I feed wrong `CC` parameter or It need more step to build Wireless Tools with cross compile?

Comment: Looks like you only modified the Makefile for just the compiler, and left unchanged other necessary macros (in spite of the directives in comments). "*but the tool fail to install.*" -- That's your summation; what does that actually mean? In normal English "*install*" means "store". Do you really mean "execute"? Since you're cross-compiling, where to you intend to store these tools on the host (before you download them to the target)? Does your toolchain match the libraries already stored in the target's root filesystem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean "execute". I rely that they use different interpreters. It should use ld-uClibc.so.0, not ld.so.1.  So I add muclibc to LDFLAGS and CFLAGS, also change AR and RANLIB directories. It works now.